# Knn classifier graph

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, knn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to build a knn graph. but when i run this code mentioned below it throws me an error 
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data' "

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTKAgg')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets

# importing data
dis = pd.read_csv("disease.csv")

# take the first two features
X = dis.data[:, :2]  
y = dis.target

print(X)
```

The CSV file looks like this :
[This is the screenshot of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW1te.png)

Comment: If any changes in the csv file is required then please do let me know

Comment: there is no need for `dis.data[:, :2]` just do `dis.values[:, :2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using `dis.data[:, :2]`.

You are trying to access an attribute named `data` of your dataframe `dis`. But Pandas dataframe have no attribute called `data`.

In your code, you are trying to access first two columns of the dataframe. You can do that by slicing the dataframe after taking the `values` of the dataframe.

In codes you can do the following.

```
dis.values[:, :2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `dis.data` as you have used. There should be an attribute named `data` in your CSV file header. But your CSV file headers contain `A,B,C..`.

So, you can access those particular columns using `dis.A` for column A or `dis.B` for column B. Since, there is no column is your CSV named `data`, you are getting the `AttributeError`.

If you want to select multiple columns at once you can simply use

```
X = dis[dis.columns[0:2]]
```

Similarly, you can get all your target values as,

```
y = dis.Species
```